# Guaranteed publishing of messages on RabbitMQ on network loss

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I am using the RabbitMQ .NET client and our services are losing messages when the network gets disconnected. 
I've tried to write a test application and use the "BasicAcks" event and resend every message that did not get an acknowledge when the disconnect happens, but it is still losing messages. The disconnect is detected with the ConnectionShutdown event (looking for ReplyCode "451").
To check the received messages, I consume all of them and read the content, which should contain at least every number from 0 to 49999 once.
It's working perfectly when the network is stable. When simulating an instable network (disabling network adapter), sometimes up to hundreds of messages are lost.

Here is the code:

```cs
private static ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> sendQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();
private static ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, byte[]> waitingForAck = new ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, byte[]>();
private static bool stop;

private static void Main()
{
    var server = "192.168.1.123";
    var userName = "rabbitmq";
    var password = "rabbitmq";
    var sendCount = 50000;
    try
    {
        Task.Run(() => Send(server, userName, password, "TestExchange", sendCount));

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Total sent:{0}", totalPackages.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Packages waiting in send queue:{0}", sendQueue.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Packages waiting for ack:{0}", waitingForAck.Count);
                Console.WriteLine();

                if (stop)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });

        Console.ReadLine();

        stop = true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", exception.Message);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void Send(string server, string userName, string password, string exchangeName, int sendCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sendCount; i++)
    {
        var content = String.Format("Hello World: {0}", i);
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        sendQueue.Enqueue(data);
    }

    var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = server, UserName = userName, Password = password };
    factory.AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true;
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionShutdown += Connection_ConnectionShutdown;

        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, ExchangeType.Fanout, false, false, null);

            channel.ConfirmSelect();

            channel.BasicAcks += Channel_BasicAcks;

            while (!stop)
            {
                byte[] data;
                if (!sendQueue.TryDequeue(out data))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    continue;
                }
                if (data == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                    var publishTag = channel.NextPublishSeqNo;

                    try
                    {
                        if (!waitingForAck.TryAdd(publishTag, data))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Cannot prepare {0}", publishTag);
                        }

                        channel.BasicPublish(exchangeName, string.Empty, null, data);
                        totalPackages.Enqueue(data);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        byte[] ignored;
                        if (!waitingForAck.TryRemove(publishTag, out ignored))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("cannot delete - exception");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Requeue {0}", publishTag);
                        sendQueue.Enqueue(data);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        continue;
                    }

            }

            while (waitingForAck.Count > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for missing acks");
            }
        }
    }            
}

private static void Channel_BasicAcks(object sender, BasicAckEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] ignored;
    if (e.Multiple)
    {
        var ids = waitingForAck.Keys.Where(x => x <= e.DeliveryTag).ToArray();
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            if (!waitingForAck.TryRemove(id, out ignored))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("cannot delete {0}", id);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!waitingForAck.TryRemove(e.DeliveryTag, out ignored))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("cannot delete {0}", e.DeliveryTag);
        }
    }
}

private static void Connection_ConnectionShutdown(object sender, ShutdownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ReplyCode == 541)
    {
        var temp = waitingForAck.Values.ToList();
        waitingForAck.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection lost, requeue {0} messages", temp.Count);
        foreach (var message in temp)
        {
            sendQueue.Enqueue(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The posted code is just the test harness, not your actual RabbitMQ code.  It might help to post your RabbitMQ code (the contents of the `Send(...)` method)

Comment: Just scroll down the code, it's all in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem wasn't the sending part, it was the receiving part. I made a mistake on checking the number 'i' at the end of each message `String.Format("Hello World: {0}", i);`

The code above is working perfectly fine, all messages are sent at least once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a durable Queue:

```
channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: true);
```

As in [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html) example.

Comment: There is already a durable queue bound to the exchange, receiving all the messages. As I said, it's working fine when the network connection is stable..